# grep regex how to get only results with one preceeding word?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, subdomain

My string is :

```
www.abc.texas.com
mail.texas.com
subdomain.xyz.cc.texas.com
www2.texas.com
```

I an trying to get results only with "one" word before texas.com. Expectation when I do a regex grep :

```
mail.texas.com
www2.texas.com
```

So mail & www2 are the "one" word that I'm talking about. I tried :

grep "*.texas.com", but I get all of them in results. Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sh
grep '^[^.]*\.texas\.com'
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^.]*` - zero or more chars other than a `.` char
- `\.texas\.com` - `.texas.com` string (literal `.` char must be escaped in the regex pattern).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/nZoFxC):

```
#!/bin/bash
s='www.abc.texas.com
mail.texas.com
subdomain.xyz.cc.texas.com
www2.texas.com'
grep '^[^.]*\.texas\.com' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
mail.texas.com
www2.texas.com
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} /texas.com$/ && NF==3' file
```

Output:

```
mail.texas.com
www2.texas.com
```

Set one dot as input and output field separator, check for `texas.com` at the end (`$`) of your line and check for three fields.

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, NR, **NF**, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F'.' 'NF==3 && $2=="texas" && $3=="com"'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple making field separator as `.` for all the lines in `awk` program. Then in main program checking condition if NF==3(means number of fields in current line)are 3 AND 2nd field is `texas` and 3rd field is `com` if all 3 conditions are MET then print the line.